# The binary operator NotEqual is not defined for the types

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to filter some elements like this:

```
model = model.Where(feature => item
            .Input
            .Contains(feature
                   .GetType()
                   .GetProperty(item.Attribute)
                   .GetValue(feature)
                   .ToString()));
```

`item` is an object that receives data about the filtering, for instance `item.Input` is a `List<string>` containing what the user filled in and `item.Attribute` (is `string`) is the column I'm supposed to look at. The field I've tested the error on is a field of type `Guid?` and it's called `AssignedUserId` and the curious thing is that this works:

```
model = model.Where(feature => item.Input.Contains(feature.AssignedUserId.ToString()));
```

As a note, this works:

```
model = model.Where(feature => feature
     .GetType()
     .GetProperty(item.Attribute)
     .GetValue(feature)
     .ToString() == item.Input.ElementAt(0));
```

So `item.Attribute` is populated well, and the filter works.

The error I'm getting is:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The binary operator NotEqual is not defined for the types 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueBuffer' and 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueBuffer'.
```

What's the problem with getting the field value like in the first code sample?

Comment: do you have any join on your query?

Answer (score 2):

which version of entityframework are u using?

i got the same error and this is already fixed in  **2.1.0-preview1** release like is discussed here [issue 9771](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9771)